# How to give values to LogisticRegression from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, machine-learning

**Here is the question**
 "params" dictionary imported below contains the parameters of Logistic Regression function that we want to update. Below is also imported and called LogisticRegression function which is defined in a way as we usually define functions. The output contains the default parameters of the function as we did not provide any parameters. Provide "params" dictionary as an input to to LogisticRegression function to update the parameters of the function (1 line of code)

```
params = {"C" : 0.01, "class_weight" : "balanced", "max_iter" : 10000,
          "n_jobs" : -1, "penalty" : "l1", "random_state" : 42}

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
use=['{}={}'.format(x,y) for (x,y) in params.items()]
print(use)
LogisticRegression(use)
```

**I do in this way but it puts the input in "Penalty"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [** dictionary unpacking](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html) to unpack the dictionary key/value pairs into the function call:

```
params = {"C" : 0.01, "class_weight" : "balanced", "max_iter" : 10000,
          "n_jobs" : -1, "penalty" : "l1", "random_state" : 42}

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

LogisticRegression(**params)
LogisticRegression(C=0.01, class_weight='balanced', dual=False,
                   fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None,
                   max_iter=10000, multi_class='auto', n_jobs=-1, penalty='l1',
                   random_state=42, solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,
                   warm_start=False)
```